# ggplot2 legend items in a single horizontal row

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

It seems that the code I wrote and tested last week has now suddenly decided to change the output even though nothing in the code or the version of R or Rstudio has changed.

Previously when I drew a plot with ggplot2 and asked for the legend to appear at the bottom of the plot, it automatically oriented the items into a single horizontal row. Now when I run the same code it places the item in a number of 2-row columns.

Here's an example:

```
mtcars$cyl <- (1:32)
subcars <- subset(mtcars, cyl<10)
subcars$cyl <- as.factor(subcars$cyl)

ggplot(subcars, aes(carb, mpg, group=cyl, colour=cyl)) + 
  geom_line() +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = rel(2), face="bold", vjust=-4)) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  theme(legend.direction = "horizontal") +
  labs(title="Title")
```

As you can see, I have already tried adding in the line `theme(legend.direction = "horizontal")` but I still get a legend which displays the items in 5 2-row columns (yes, its not even just in two rows).

Now I can only assume that there has been some update that I was not aware of or something, so I'm willing to accept that I need to come up with a new strategy for dealing with this problem (which just wasn't a problem last week). Although I am a little bit confused about why my code has suddenly decided to stop working (any input on this welcome), I'm more interested in finding a fix for the immediate problem of my legend items being displayed in a strange configuration.

Comment: If the below answer helped you, please do not add "Thanks" as comment, instead, accept it. This can be done by clicking the check mark below the voting arrows, and gives both you and the answerer a bit of reputation. This signals to the community at large that you no longer require help with this problem. This is not obligatory, just the Stack Overflow way of things.

Answer (score 130):

Add this to your plot:

```
+ guides(colour = guide_legend(nrow = 1))
```

Comment: And of course if the legend follows a `fill` rather than a `colour` aesthetic, it's `+ guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 1))`